# Имплементация интерфейсов и ключевое слово this

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Разбираю готовое приложение под android, следующие строки кода вызывают непонимание.

```
public interface Interface_1 {

    void interface_1 ();
}

public interface Interface_2 {

    void interface_2 ();
}

public class MyClass_1{
     public Interface_1 interface_1;

     public MyClass_1 (Interface_1 interface_1){
         this.interface_1= interface_1;
     }
}

public class MyClass_2{
     public Interface_2 interface_2;

     public MyClass_2 (Interface_2 interface_2){
         this.interface_1= interface_1;
     }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Interface_1 , Interface_2  {

new Interface_1 (this);
new Interface_2 (this);

@Override
    public void interface_1() {
       //Реализация метода 
    }
@Override
    public void interface_2() {
       //Реализация метода 
    }
```

Объясните пожалуйста почему это работает, ведь насколько я понимаю в данном случае this это ссылка на MainActivity, а при создании объектов нужно передать ссылки на объекты interface_1 и interface_2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> насколько я понимаю в данном случае this это ссылка на MainActivity

Верно понимаете.

> при создании объектов нужно передать ссылки на объекты interface_1 и
>   interface_2

И тут все верно.

> почему это работает

Потому, что `MainActivity` имплементит интерфейсы `Interface_1` и `Interface_2`. То есть, если по простотому, то `MainActivity` это и `Interface_1` и `Interface_2` и `AppCompatActivity` и `Context` и ещё много всего, что наследуют или имплементят все её родительские классы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.